# PHP includes, relative src attributes, and Apache error pages

Tags: php, include, http-status-code-404

I am using a 404 error page found at:

```
/error_pages/404.php
```

I have a regular page template used for displaying all kinds of messages to the user at:

```
/message.php
```

My error page looks like this:

```
require_once("../includes/core.php");

$message = "Sorry but we could no longer find the item that you were looking for";
$messageStart = "Not Found";

require_once("../message.php");
```

I have an admin page found at:

```
/admin
```

Now my problem is the CSS files and JS files at `message.php`. If the 404 happened at document root, all links are resolved to their proper locations and all files are included in the HTML. If the 404 happened at `/admin`, all links are resolved as if `message.php` is found at `/admin/message.php`!

I already tried using a constant like `PATH_TO_ROOT` which is defined per page, or it is defined by `core.php` depending on the value of $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].

Now the problem in the above approach is that $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] always contains `/error_pages/404.php` thus `PATH_TO_ROOT` will always contain `'../'` and will mess-up all 404's happening at document root.

If I define `PATH_TO_ROOT` within `message.php` itself, then all 404's in `/admin` gets messed up.

How do I solve this?

**EDIT:**

I tried using $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. The CSS and JS files are now properly included. The problem is the PHP includes. All includes are resolved from `/error_pages` where `404.php` is located. These PHP includes do use `PATH_TO_ROOT` so a `PATH_TO_ROOT` based on `REQUEST_URI` is really not that good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done this in my own framework the solution can be a bit aggravating to get to and not well documented by many others on the web.  There are really 3 problems you have to account for:

- Where is the WEB root and where is your engine/framework code located accordingly
- Where is the PHP files root for your engine/framework and includes/requires accordingly
- Calculation of proper pathing for CSS/JS/Images/etc...

Assuming a few minor details these can all be worked around easily enough.  First assumption to make is that your framework will be in a known folder (call it framework) and that it will have a known file name (again, framework.php).  Then to find the framework path in your index.php handler you can use:

```
// in index.php
$frameworkPath = './';
while((is_dir($frameworkPath))&&(!file_exists($frameworkPath.'framework/framework.php'))){
  $frameworkPath = ($frameworkPath!='./')?'../'.$frameworkPath:'../';
}
if(!file_exists($frameworkPath.'framework/framework.php')){
// some type of error handler here
}else require_once($frameworkPath.'framework/framework.php');

// in framework.php
if(!defined('FRAMEWORK_PATH')){
  $frameworkpath = str_replace("\\", '/', dirname(__file__));
  if(substr($frameworkpath, -1)!='/') $frameworkpath .= '/';
  define('FRAMEWORK_PATH', $frameworkpath);
}
// now your requires become require_once(FRAMEWORK_PATH.'filename/relative/framework.php');
```

Then we need to calculate the Site's installed path.We can do this using the DOCUMENT_ROOT and the path to the "currently accessed file".  Something similar to the following:

```
$serverPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$thisPath = @realpath(dirname('./'));
$thisPathLength = strlen($thisPath);
$SitePath = '/'.str_replace('\\','/', substr($thisPath, strlen($serverPath), $thisPathLength)).'/';
```

This also provides us the absolute path for the sites PHP files and we can take advantage of the fact that the PHP include system lets us give absolute file paths and not just relative ones for inclusion of user scripts.  thisPath is what is used for user script includes and requires.  If for example you want to include a file in /path/to/site/user_script.php you can do a:

```
require_once($thisPath.'user_script.php');
```

SitePath can now be used to setup includes related to CSS/JS/etc files.  So instead of stating

```
<img src="img.jpg" />
```

you say

```
<img src="<?php echo $SitePath;?>img.jpg" />.
```

If your interested I've got my current framework to a point where its shareable, eventually I'm going to release it Open Source but I haven't done the documentation so its a read at your own risk type of thing :).  I extended this to use SIMPLE_HTML_DOM_PARSER so it updates the tags in the source HTML for the designer and they don't have to worry about src, action, href, etc attributes on tags.  Sure, it slows down rendering a bit, but it makes the designers lives so much easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Use links relative to the *site* root:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/default.css" />
```

Use a forward slash at the beginning of the path to "start" at the site's root folder. This way, the path is always the same.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible since this is actually a CMS and I really don't know if the client's site will be located at http://hisdomain.com or at http://hishost.com/user

Comment: Well, that is a REALLY important thing to know when developing a website, and knowing that will solve this problem.

Comment: I simply used absolute paths. Something like $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) . blah blah blah. Thanks for the time though

Comment: That is the root of your problem. If you use a template, you can't use  "dotted" paths.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I if I understand well your question, and you really want to use relative not absolute paths (like /css/style.css) I would try to calculate the depth of the current document with something like:

```
$depth = substr_count($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_URI"], "/") - 1;
```

And then for the path use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=str_repeat("../", $depth)?>css/style.css" />
```

I didn't tested the code but it should work. Try it out.
Hope it helped